# keyboard interrupt handler giving null value

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I am learning Linux Kernel Module programming(Interrupt Handler) and using the tutorial (http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/) exact module link(http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x1256.html).

In the tutorial I am getting error when I used

```
INIT_WORK(&task, got_char, &scancode);
```

The error was "error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2"

So I found one solution and use the below line

```
INIT_WORK(&task, got_char);
```

It's working fine but the output I am  getting is null. I am expecting the key number from the keyboard.

Any body have any idea ?

If it is not clear please let me know I will try to interpret more.

Thanks

Comment: INIT_WORK() takes different parameters in the newer kernels.  A pointer to an IRQ work queue struct and handler are needed now.  For an example, see: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/musb/musb_core.c#L1875 -- `static void foo_irq_work(struct work_struct *data)`

Comment: Which kernel version are you using ?

Comment: The bottom half handler function (in your case got_char()) takes struct work_struct * as it's argument. You should figure out a way of passing values from top half to bottom half.

Answer (score 4):

Add a structure like follows,

```
struct getchar_info {
    /* Other info ... */
    struct work_struct work;
    unsigned int scancode;
    /* Other info ... */
};
static struct getchar_info gci; /* Statically declare or use kmalloc() */
```

Change `got_char()` to,

```
static void got_char(struct work_struct *work)
{
    struct getchar_info *info = container_of(work, struct getchar_info, work);
    info->scancode = my_val;
    /* ... */
```

Initialize it like `INIT_WORK(&gci.work, got_char);`

This is a common *Linux kernel* paradigm or [design pattern](http://lwn.net/Articles/336224/).  The *work queue* code needs to manage this structure pointer so it is easy to provide to your `got_char` routine.  Your driver must allocate it as part of a *larger* structure (it is *inheritence* in OO terms; it looks like [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) as 'C' only supports that).  The `container_of` is like a C++ `dynamic_cast<>` (with single inheritance in case any C++ *gurus* are looking).  It lets you get the *composed* structure from the *sub-structure*.

Comment: This answer is mainly motivated by [VivekS's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2768457/vivek-s) comment.